# why the output of C program is wrong?i have checked for a long time

Tags: c

Here is the C source file i write, after i run it, i input  1  1 -2 1 , but the output is not x1=1.000000,x2=1.000000? the output is x1=2.000000,x2=2.000000 .

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void fun(float a, float b, float c);

int main()
{
int n,i;
float a, b, c;

printf("please enter the times you want to try:\n");

scanf("%d", &n);

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    printf("please enter the a,b,c:\n");
    scanf("%f%f%f", &a, &b, &c);
    fun(a, b, c);
}
return 0;
}

void fun(float d, float e, float f) {
float x1, x2;

if (e*e - 4 * d*f < 0)
    printf("no answer\n");
if (e*e - 4 * d*f >= 0) {
    x1 = (-e + sqrt(e*e - 4 * d*f)) / (2 * d); //should work better
    x2 = (-e - sqrt(e*e - 4 * d*f)) / (2 * d);
    printf("the roots are x1=%f x2=%f\n", x1, x2);
    }
}
```

Comment: That code doesn't even compile (mismatched parentheses). Please show your real program. FWIW, if I put the missing close parentheses in the right place, I do get the right answers.

Comment: Maybe there are also operator precedence issues. Try using explicit parenthesis.

Comment: is sqrt(e*e - 4 * d*f) = 0? as per your input? and you might be getting devide by zero error

Comment: sorry, i forget to add the parentheses in the right place, but the answer is also wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x1 = (-e + sqrt(e*e - 4 * d*f)) / (2 * d);
x2 = (-e - sqrt(e*e - 4 * d*f)) / (2 * d);
```